# I can´t copy my MP3 file from raw to external storage in android

Tags: java, android

I want copy a mp3 file to external storage, that i can share it over whatsapp or something like that.

I get some issues:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Music/Arno lacht. (Is a directory)

How i can create a file? Im new in programming sry...

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

```
    switch (requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNALSTORAGE:{

            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.


                //  External Storage accessible?

                String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

                    try{

                        // Create path


                        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC) ;



                            File root = new File(path, "Sounds");

                            if(!root.exists()) {
                                // Create new directory

                                root.mkdirs();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ordner wurde erstellt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }



                        // Make sure the music directory exists.



                        File file = new File(root, soundNamenArray.get(itemPosition) );

                        // Copy data from internal memory to external memory

                        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(soundId[itemPosition]);

                        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];

                        int length;

                        while (( length = is.read(data)) > 0){
                            os.write(data, 0, length);

                        }

                        is.close();
                        os.close();


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datei kopiert!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                    }catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception geworfen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }




                    // Intent zum verschicken Starten
                    teilenIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    teilenIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
                    teilenIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(teilenIntent, "Sound teilen"));  


                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fehler", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request.



    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what **exactly** isn't working on the copy process. Do you see any Exceptions in the debugging console?

Comment: I only see this: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY) And it looks like that somthing went wrong with my FileInputStream..

Comment: it have to be a IOException

Comment: I do not have any training in this area.

Comment: I do programming just for fun

Comment: ok i found now this java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Music/Sounds (Permission denied)

Comment: Ok i gues i know now the bug, it seems that the system dont have permission for writing in external storage. But i have already add this to the manifest      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: If you run Android 6+, you need to actually request the permission before you can use it (And not just define it in the manifest).

Comment: What is my mistake? netlink response contains error (No such file or directory)

Comment: Well, for that, I need to know which version of the Android SDK you're using. I don't where you can find that, so you may need to Google for that.